# Android. How to invoke a search

Tags: android, search

I have seen the Searchable Dictionary v2 tutorial in Google Android site - http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SearchableDictionary/index.html. Inside it a search provider has been implemented, and it's possibile to invoke a search through ACTION_SEARCH.
Now i'd like to create a button and assign a term to it and with a clic to invoke a search with the specified term, but i can't understand how to do this.
Could you please give me some advices, as you can imagine i'm new with android.
I'd like to put the button in a new activity, and use the "showResults(String query)" in the SearchableDictionary activity. How can i do it?

ie. I have the button "dog" and when i clic it i'd like to get the results for "dog" word, without have to put the term or to have it suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke search via [onSearchRequested()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSearchRequested%28%29) method on your Activity class. Good Luck!

Comment: Yes i know it. But i'd like to invoke a search with a predefined word and not to invoke the search interface.

ie. I have the button "dog" and when i clic it i'd like to get the results for "dog" word, without have to put the term or to have it suggested.